# How to retrieve a picture inserted in the database from 1st to 2nd activity?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I can't retrieve the image from a database in my second activity.

```
     import android.content.Intent;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            import com.example.dell.egyptholidayapp.Helper.DatabaseHelper;
            import com.example.dell.egyptholidayapp.R;

            public class MyAccountPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                private TextView Username, Email, Nationality, Gender, Age, Mobile;
                private Button Edit;

                private ImageView ivImage2;

                String user, email, nationality, gender, age, mobile;

                Bundle bundle;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account_page);
                    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null){
                        int resId = bundle.getInt("resId");
                        ivImage2.setImageResource(resId);
                    }

                    user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME");
                    email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EMAIL");
                    nationality = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NATIONALITY");
                    gender = getIntent().getExtras().getString("GENDER");
                    age = getIntent().getExtras().getString("AGE");
                    mobile = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MOBILE");

                    ivImage2 = findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);

                    Username = findViewById(R.id.username_v);
                    Email = findViewById(R.id.email_v);
                    Nationality = findViewById(R.id.nationality_v);
                    Gender = findViewById(R.id.gender_v);
                    Age = findViewById(R.id.age_v);
                    Mobile = findViewById(R.id.mobile_v);
                    Edit = findViewById(R.id.edit_btn);

                    Username.setText(" " + user);
                    Email.setText(" " + email);
                    Nationality.setText(" " + nationality);
                    Gender.setText(" " + gender);
                    Age.setText(" " + age);
                    Mobile.setText(" " + mobile);

                    Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MyAccountPageActivity.this, EditMyAccountActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });



                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you please share what's happening with you? if there is an exception or that nothing happens at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is alright, considering that the IDs you are sending from Activity1 to Activity2 are correct, the only problem with your code is that you are using `ivImage2` without initializing it first so what you have to do first is find the image view then use it to set the image you sent from Activity1, your code should be like this:

```
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account_page);
                //You should move this line here and everything will work as you want it to
                ivImage2 = findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);

                bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (bundle != null){
                    int resId = bundle.getInt("resId");
                    ivImage2.setImageResource(resId);
                }

                user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME");
                email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EMAIL");
                nationality = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NATIONALITY");
                gender = getIntent().getExtras().getString("GENDER");
                age = getIntent().getExtras().getString("AGE");
                mobile = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MOBILE");
```

Comment: it did not send to the second activity but i will send you the code of the first activity.

Comment: Then tell us what is the problem, what happened? is there an exception? or what? please explain as much as you can so we can help you with this

Comment: the second activity is about profile pages showing data from the first activity all the data appears except the data captured by the mobile camera or got from gallery

Comment: should i use uri or not?